Referencing correctAnswer in a separate field
I want to reference the 'correctAnswer' of a radio-button group question and populate the value into another field.
So the field will show the correctAnswer of the first field, regardless of what the user entered.
Is this possible?
See attached field with expected expression:
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Directly using {question1.correctAnswer} will not result in what you need because the expressions parser of SurveyJS does not directly provide access to the details of the question definition.
A solution is to use custom async functions in expressions. These are JS functions that you can define, register in the FunctionFactory of the Survey object and then use in the expressions.
I don't know what your setup for rendering the form is but I created an example with React that you can check here.
Main points

In index.js there is a function getCorrectAnswer(questionName)

function getCorrectAnswer(questionName) {
    const question = this.survey.getQuestionByName(questionName);
    return this.returnResult(question.jsonObj.correctAnswer);
}


In index.js the function getCorrectAnswer is registered in FunctionFactory

Survey.FunctionFactory.Instance.register("getCorrectAnswer", getCorrectAnswer, true);


json.js contains the form definition and the defined function is used there like "expression": "getCorrectAnswer('question1')"

Note
If you don't use React, the solution should be quite similar. You can check examples at Asynchronous Functions in Expressions

You can actually access a correctAnswer property value in expressions. Use the `propertyValue('questionName', 'correctAnswer') function to get the correct value in expressions.
